# Swap first and last array in multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, swap

I have a multidimensional array in the following format

```
$pet = array(
     array(
            'name' => 'Chew Barka',
            'breed' => 'Bichon',
            'age'  => '2 years',
            'weight' => 8,
         'bio'   => 'The park, The pool or the Playground - I love to go anywhere! I am really great at... SQUIRREL!',
            'filename' => 'pet1.png'
    ),
    array(
            'name' => 'Spark Pug',
            'breed' => 'Pug',
            'age'  => '1.5 years',
            'weight' => 11,
            'bio'   => 'You want to go to the dog park in style? Then I am your pug!',
            'filename' => 'pet2.png'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Pico de Gato',
            'breed' => 'Bengal',
            'age'  => '5 years',
            'weight' => 9,
            'bio'   => 'Oh hai, if you do not have a can of salmon I am not interested.',
            'filename' => 'pet3.png'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Name',
            'breed' => 'Breed',
            'age'  => 'Age',
            'weight' => 'Weight',
            'bio'   => 'Biography',
            'filename' => 'Filename'
    )
);
```

I need to swap the last array with the first. I tried to do this

```
function arraySwap(&$array, $swap_a, $swap_b){
    list($array[$swap_a], $array[$swap_b]) = array($array[$swap_b], $array[$swap_a]);
}
```

This does swap the arrays first with last. However what i need is to push the arrays bellow. So once i swap the last array with the first, the first needs to come to position 1, the one at position 1 goes to 2 etc.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you show a mock-up of your expected result?

Comment: The accepted answer merely moves the last row to the front of the array.  Is that what your question is asking? I f8nd this question to be unclearly expressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are just interested to shift the heading array on the top, you can do some circular array shifting like below

```
$arr = array(
     array(
            'name' => 'Chew Barka',
            'breed' => 'Bichon',
            'age'  => '2 years',
            'weight' => 8,
         'bio'   => 'The park, The pool or the Playground - I love to go anywhere! I am really great at... SQUIRREL!',
            'filename' => 'pet1.png'
    ),
    array(
            'name' => 'Spark Pug',
            'breed' => 'Pug',
            'age'  => '1.5 years',
            'weight' => 11,
            'bio'   => 'You want to go to the dog park in style? Then I am your pug!',
            'filename' => 'pet2.png'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Pico de Gato',
            'breed' => 'Bengal',
            'age'  => '5 years',
            'weight' => 9,
            'bio'   => 'Oh hai, if you do not have a can of salmon I am not interested.',
            'filename' => 'pet3.png'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Name',
            'breed' => 'Breed',
            'age'  => 'Age',
            'weight' => 'Weight',
            'bio'   => 'Biography',
            'filename' => 'Filename'
    )
);

echo "<pre>";
$key=count($arr)-1;
$output1 = array_slice($arr, $key); 
$output2 = array_slice($arr, 0,$key); 
$new=array_merge($output1,$output2);
print_r($new);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Name
            [breed] => Breed
            [age] => Age
            [weight] => Weight
            [bio] => Biography
            [filename] => Filename
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Chew Barka
            [breed] => Bichon
            [age] => 2 years
            [weight] => 8
            [bio] => The park, The pool or the Playground - I love to go anywhere! I am really great at... SQUIRREL!
            [filename] => pet1.png
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Spark Pug
            [breed] => Pug
            [age] => 1.5 years
            [weight] => 11
            [bio] => You want to go to the dog park in style? Then I am your pug!
            [filename] => pet2.png
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Pico de Gato
            [breed] => Bengal
            [age] => 5 years
            [weight] => 9
            [bio] => Oh hai, if you do not have a can of salmon I am not interested.
            [filename] => pet3.png
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just slice the first and last items from the array, and then re-assemble it using `array_merge`.

Example:

```php
function swapFirstAndLast($array) {
    return array_merge(
        array_slice($array, -1 , 1), // Last item
        array_slice($array, 1 , count($array) - 2), // Second - Second last items
        array_slice($array, 0 , 1) // First item
    );
}

var_dump(array_column(swapFirstAndLast($pet), 'name'));

//array(4) {
//    [0] =>
//  string(4) "Name"
//    [1] =>
//  string(9) "Spark Pug"
//    [2] =>
//  string(12) "Pico de Gato"
//    [3] =>
//  string(10) "Chew Barka"
//}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of ways to skin this cat. Here are two functions, the first always swaps first and last elements, the second swaps arbitrary elements. I've shown how you can use that function to easily swap first and last. You could use the logic from the arraySwap function in the arraySwapFirstLast function instead of the [array_shift](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php), [array_unshift](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php), and  [array_pop](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php), and it would probably be more efficient, but this demonstrates some important array manipulation functions. The simple logic in arraySwap is what you would use in textbook sorting algorithms and is very efficient.

```
<?php
$pet = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Chew Barka',
        'breed' => 'Bichon',
        'age'  => '2 years',
        'weight' => 8,
        'bio'   => 'The park, The pool or the Playground - I love to go anywhere! I am really great at... SQUIRREL!',
        'filename' => 'pet1.png'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Spark Pug',
        'breed' => 'Pug',
        'age'  => '1.5 years',
        'weight' => 11,
        'bio'   => 'You want to go to the dog park in style? Then I am your pug!',
        'filename' => 'pet2.png'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Pico de Gato',
        'breed' => 'Bengal',
        'age'  => '5 years',
        'weight' => 9,
        'bio'   => 'Oh hai, if you do not have a can of salmon I am not interested.',
        'filename' => 'pet3.png'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Name',
        'breed' => 'Breed',
        'age'  => 'Age',
        'weight' => 'Weight',
        'bio'   => 'Biography',
        'filename' => 'Filename'
    )
);

$pet1 = $pet;
$pet2 = $pet;

/**
 * Swap the first and last elements of an array
 * Uses shift/unshift and standard array append
 * @param $array
 */
function arraySwapFirstLast(&$array)
{
    $first = array_shift($array);
    $last  = array_pop($array);
    array_unshift($array, $last);
    $array[] = $first;
}

/**
 * Swap two arbitrary array elements
 * @param $array
 * @param $index1
 * @param $index2
 */
function arraySwap(&$array, $index1, $index2)
{
    $swapEl = $array[$index1];

    $array[$index1] = $array[$index2];
    $array[$index2] = $swapEl;
}

arraySwapFirstLast($pet);
echo 'arraySwapFirstLast:'.PHP_EOL;
print_r($pet).PHP_EOL;

arraySwap($pet1, 1, 2);
echo 'arraySwap second and third elements:'.PHP_EOL;
print_r($pet1).PHP_EOL;

arraySwap($pet2, 0, sizeof($pet2)-1);
echo 'arraySwap first and last elements:'.PHP_EOL;
print_r($pet2).PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use:

```
$arr1 = $pet[0];
$arr2 = $pet[count($pet)-1];
$pet[0] = $arr2;
$pet[count($pet)-1] = $arr1;
print_r($pet);
```